# Как правильно указать путь сохранения файла?

Tags: java, android

Есть метод:

```
 public void writeToFile(String fileName, String write_text) {
    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, 0);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        osw.write(write_text);
        osw.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) { Log.d("MyLog","Exception: " + t.toString()); }
}
```

Использую так:

```
String str = "1234567890";
writeToFile("Base/"+default_base,str);
```

Если убрать путь `Base/`, то запись проходит.

Если оставить, то выходит ошибка:

> Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File Base/default_base
>   contains a path separator

То же самое с чтением:

```
public String readStringFromFile(String fileName) {
    String rep="";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { builder.append(line + "\n"); }
            inputStream.close();
            rep =  builder.toString();
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {Log.d("MyLog","Exception: " + t.toString()); }
    return rep;
}
```

В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: В самом начале метода `writeToFile(...)` выведите в лог переменную `fileName` и покажите ее значение, когда приложение падает и когда не падает.

Comment: Методы `openFileInput / openFileOutput` принимают только имя файла, поддиректории не поддерживаются.

Comment: fileName: Base/default_base или fileName: default_base

Comment: Если эти методы принимают только имена, то какие варианты есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте классы `FileInputStream` и `FileOutputStream`:

```
FileInputStream fistream = new FileInputStream(new File(YourFile));
```